# Kotlin Type Constraints

Tags: kotlin, generics

Whats the difference between the two methods below? They both have the same type constraints but im confused on what i should use

```
class Logger<T> {
    fun <T : CharSequence> onLog(line: T) {

    }
    fun <T> onLogSecond(line: T) where T : CharSequence {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same in your example so use the first one for code readability. The second version is typically only used when you have multiple constraints for the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to kotlin documentation [Generic Constraints](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#generic-constraints)

> Only **one upper bound** can be specified inside the angle brackets. If the same type parameter needs more than one upper bound, you need a separate where-clause:

So if you only have one bound, put it inside the angle brackets.
If you have more than one bound, use where-clause.